# Нежелательный пересчёт :style

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Изменение свойства одного объекта приводит к новому пересчёту у других объектов:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    test: [{
      value: 'I am a test object',
      isColor: true
    }, {
      value: 'I am just another a test object',
      isColor: false
    }, {
      value: 'Yippee-kai-yay',
      isColor: true
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    color: _ => '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div v-for="(o, i) in test" :key="i">
    <span :style="{ color: o.isColor ? color() : 'black' }">{{ o.value }}</span><br />
  </div><br />
  <input type='text' v-model="test[1].value" /> |
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="test[1].isColor" />
  <hr />
  Тут грязных хак используется для кэширования, но пересчёт у всех левых элементов всё ещё идёт.
  <div v-for="(o, i) in test" :key="i">
    <span :style="{ color: o.isColor ? o._color || (o._color = color()) : 'black' }">{{ o.value }}</span><br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Я так понимаю что `Vue` перестраховывается и пересчитывает заново, а там каждый раз новый цвет, а значит виртуальный DOM решает обновлять реальный, это понятно.
Но зачем всех пересчитывать и как это прекратить?
Ведь элементов может быть много и, возможно, вместо рандомного цвета будет что-то тяжелее, зачем лишняя нагрузка странице?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам в любом случае придётся использовать свойства и поддерживать их актуальность самостоятельно. При использовании методов, Vue.js обязан вызвать их и в случае изменения возвращаемого значения обновить DOM.

```js
{
  class Item {
    constructor(value, isBorder = false) {
      this.value = value;
      this.isBorder = isBorder;

      this.recolor();
    }
    recolor() {
      this.color = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
    }
  }
  new Vue({
    el: "#root",
    data: {
      test: [
        new Item('I am a test object', true),
        new Item('I am just another test object')
      ]
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <div v-for="(o, i) in test" :key="i">
    <span :style="{ border: o.isBorder ? '5px solid ' + o.color : 'none' }">{{ o.value }}</span><br />
  </div><br />
  <input type='text' v-model="test[1].value" /> |
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="test[1].isBorder" @change="test[1].recolor()" />
</div>
```

Comment: Повторюсь - пересчёт **изменённого** объекта меня не смущает, это ОК, но то, что пересчитываются остальные объекты из циклам - это проблема.

Comment: Ну так откуда ему узнать, какие именно объекты изменились? Vue.js принципиально отказался от Object.observe в пользу обычного асинхронного опроса. Т.е. он опрашивает **все** объекты на наличие изменений, не трогая DOM, если изменений нет.

Comment: Да? Чойта? Почему это? Можно объявление об этом увидеть?

Comment: Да, погуглив увидел отказ, а `Object.observe` выкинут на мороз из TC39, но всё равно стоило бы как-то хранить информацию на каком элемент месте, а то всех опрашивать - опрашивалка сломается.